# Reordering a productlist block in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm a bit of a Magento noob. I have the following code in the Page Layout section of my home page:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>8</category_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

How do I change what attribute the products in this block are ordered by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of a product list is generally controlled by the toolbar block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`. But if you want to be able to influence the way the product collection is ordered from the layout, you can do the following:

Rewrite the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and add a function to it:

```
public function setOrder($attribute, $direction) 
{
    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();
    $collection->clear()->setOrder($attribute, $direction);
    $this->_productCollection = $collection;
}
```

in the layout update add an action node, e.g.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>8</category_id></action>
        <action method="setOrder"><attribute>name</attribute><direction>desc</direction></action>
</block>
```